# How to get the workflow back using Power Automate for SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate

I'm trying to create a workflow using the Approval connector in PowerAutomate for SPO.

I understand that I can create approvals and rejections as standard, but can I implement an approver sending the workflow back to the applicant using a custom response?
Also, is it possible to implement the applicant to send the workflow back to him/herself before the approver approves it?

I want to achieve withdrawals and retractions that are not in the standard response.

I hope above is clear for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the **Do Until** loop in Power Automate like so:

[image]

Basically, you keep creating an approval until it's finally approved. The real example will have more actions.